# How can I display Only the first Array/Object?

Tags: users, rest-api, array, api

**By using Wordpress REST Api**

```
./wp/v2/users/?_fields=id&orderby=id&order=desc
```

Result

```
[{"id":13},{"id":12},{"id":11},{"id":10},{"id":9},{"id":8},{"id":6},{"id":5},{"id":4},{"id":3}]
```

**What I want?**

I just want to display [{"id":13},
Means, I want to limit it to only 1 array Using REST API. Any one have solution on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/) show that you can do paging with `page` and `per_page`, so looks like you should be able to set `per_page` to `1` and leave `page` unset to get a single result. i.e.:

```
./wp/v2/users/?_fields=id&orderby=id&order=desc&per_page=1
```

Does that help?

Comment: Gosh! Thanks! Yes it does help. Thank You @mozboz